# Pyspark dataframe row-wise null columns list

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe and I want to create a new column that contains the columns name having null in each row. For example

Original dataframe is:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|

+-----+-----+-----+

|62.45|null |62.49|

|56.45|null |null |

|null |null |null |

| 56.4|57.32|48.39|

+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
```

The final dataframe with the result column is:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|            Result|

+-----+-----+-----+------------------+

|62.45|null |62.49|             col_2|

|56.45|null |null |      col_2, col_3|

|null |null |null |col_1, col2, col_3|

| 56.4|57.32|48.39|                  |

+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
```

I know to get the number of null columns but looking for row-wise column names that can be different in each row. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (df.withColumn('Result', array(*[when(col(c).isNull(), lit(c)) for c in df.columns]))#Lists Columns with null

.withColumn('Result', expr("filter(Result, x -> x is not null)"))#Exludes nulls from list
 
 .show())
```

Comment: While this probably answers the question, it's hard to read without some explanations. Can you add a bit of introductory text explaining how this answer is constructed? (FYI, this post landed in the low-quality post queue.)

Comment: @joanis,  Kindly look at the answer again. Against each line of code there is a hashed explanation. Must I write textbook of explanation. Please look at my reputation, I am a seasoned contributor. Keep well man

Comment: I voted "Looks OK", because I saw that, but it would still make the answer more readable with those comments above instead. I saw your rep so I was surprised with your formatting choices, but never mind, if you feel this is good as it stands.

Comment: I'm sorry man, but your response has been bugging me for a while. I made a call you disagree with, and that's OK, Your first two sentences respond to that, which is the right thing to do. But "Please look at my rep" says higher-reppers think they're above the rules, and that cannot be the case if this site is going to work for everyone. Your answers are not to be deemed good because of your rep - it's the other way around, your rep is high because you have made a lot of good posts. Still, each of your answer is to be judged on its own merit, just like for lower-reppers and new users.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is collecting each null column with column function [`isNull`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isNull.html) then add them into an array with SQL function [`array`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html)

```py
(df
    .withColumn('Result', F.array(
        F.when(F.col('col_1').isNull(), 'col_1'),
        F.when(F.col('col_2').isNull(), 'col_2'),
        F.when(F.col('col_3').isNull(), 'col_3'),
    ))
    .show()
)

# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
# |col_1|col_2|col_3|Result               |
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
# |62.45|null |62.49|[null, col_2, null]  |
# |56.45|null |null |[null, col_2, col_3] |
# |null |null |null |[col_1, col_2, col_3]|
# |56.4 |57.32|48.39|[null, null, null]   |
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

You're obviously want to get rid of the `null`s so apply [`filter`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) would do the job (Note: `filter` only available since 3.1.0)

```py
(df
    .withColumn('Result', F.array(
        F.when(F.col('col_1').isNull(), 'col_1'),
        F.when(F.col('col_2').isNull(), 'col_2'),
        F.when(F.col('col_3').isNull(), 'col_3'),
    ))
    .withColumn('Result', F.filter(F.col('Result'), lambda c: c.isNotNull()))
 
    .show(10, False)
)

# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
# |col_1|col_2|col_3|Result               |
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
# |62.45|null |62.49|[col_2]              |
# |56.45|null |null |[col_2, col_3]       |
# |null |null |null |[col_1, col_2, col_3]|
# |56.4 |57.32|48.39|[]                   |
# +-----+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

Finally, you also can improve code's flexibility by not hardcoding the columns but using a `for` loop instead, and still got the same result:

```py
(df
    .withColumn('Result', F.array(
        *[F.when(F.col(c).isNull(), c) for c in df.columns]
    ))
    .withColumn('Result', F.filter(F.col('Result'), lambda c: c.isNotNull()))
 
    .show(10, False)
)
```