# Pyspark: Is there a way to create a dataframe column with names of other columns meeting a condition?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

In a Pyspark dataframe, is there a way to add a new column which for each record tells us which columns are null (or some other condition)?

For eg. given a dataframe

```
col1 | col2 | col1_null | col2_null |
-----|------|-----------|-----------|
a    | null |           | True      |
null |  b   |   True    |           |
null | null |   True    | True      |
```

the new dataframe will be

```
col1 | col2 | col1_null | col2_null | cols             |
-----|------|-----------|-----------|------------------|
a    | null |           |     True  | ['col2']         |
null |  b   |   True    |           | ['col1']         |
null | null |   True    | True      | ['col1', 'col2'] |
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67494153/pyspark-dataframe-row-wise-null-columns-list

Comment: Yes, that answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: cool, if that worked, you can close this question.